# ArgumentError: Error #1063: board/remove() - no argument at all

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

How can there be an argument mismatch without any arguments in either caller or object function?

```
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, remove);
        }
        private function remove():void
        { 
           trace("check");

           removeChild(start);
            start = null;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event listener's handler requires an event argument. The event dispatcher will pass the event itself as an argument to whatever handler has been registered.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, remove);
    }
    private function remove( e:MouseEvent ):void
    { 
       trace("check");

       removeChild(start);
        start = null;

    }
```

The argument's type should generally match whatever event type you are using, but it can obviously be any type that it extends as well (so `e:Event` will always work). The `e` property will be the event, so you can access properties available on the event (like in `ProgressEvent`, you have access to `bytesLoaded` and `bytesTotal`).